# Dynamically appending child nodes with Ionic CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ionic3

I want to add styles from the Ionic CSS library to the HTML element created in Javascript. The purpose is because I'm pulling objects from my database and dynamically creating buttons for them. I can receive these items and add them to the page but I'm unable to use format it properly. This is a basic HTML example of what I want to replicate in JavaScript.

```
<ion-list id="list" (click)=add()>
<button ion-item>
  <ion-icon name="ios-add" item-start></ion-icon>
  Add 
</button>
</ion-list>
```

To produce this button:

[image]

This is what I have in Javascript.

```
add() {
   var listItem = document.getElementById("list");
   var listButton = document.createElement('button');
   listButton.setAttribute("class","ion-item");
   listButton.setAttribute("id", id+"1");
   var icon = document.createElement("ion-icon");
   icon.setAttribute("name","ios-add");
   let text = document.createTextNode("Add");
   listButton.appendChild(text);
   listButton.appendChild(icon);
   listItem.appendChild(listButton);
}
```

This is what the above[code produces:

[image]

How can I use JavaScript to manipulate the DOM while retaining Ionic formatting?

Using: Node 8.3.0, Angular 4, Ionic 3.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, what I am pushing the objects to an array every time I clicked on an object, I would push it to the array created in the front-end and display the array of objects in a separate component, that way I can style only the selected items.

The other option would be to copy the whole data objects and add props of boolean type like "added" or "in_playlist" but there may be a lot of data therefore I would suggest the first solution.